# Validate a TextBox upon button press in WPF/MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `TextBox` and a `Button` in my view. I have an `ICommand` method, `String` serial number property, and a `IsEnabled` property in my view model.

When the user clicks the `Button` I'd like to validate the serial number in the `TextBox` with the `InDatabase` property. If the contents in the `TextBox` are invalid, I would like to raise an error on the `TextBox`. If the contents are valid in the `TextBox` I'd like to disable the `Button` and execute the command.

Here is the view:

```
<StackPanel Width="Auto" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <UniformGrid Rows="3"  >
        <TextBlock Text="This device appears to be uninitialized."/>
        <UniformGrid Rows="1" Columns="2">
            <Label>Serial Number:</Label>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding IdentifiedSerialNumber, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"></TextBox>
        </UniformGrid>
        <Button Content="Identify" Command="{Binding IdentifyCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding CanExecuteDeviceRestoration}"/>
    </UniformGrid>
</StackPanel>
```

Here is the view-model:

```
public string IdentifiedSerialNumber 
{
    get
    {
        return this.identifiedSerialNumber;
    }
    set
    {
        this.identifiedSerialNumber = value;
    }
}

public ICommand IdentifyCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new RelayCommand(this.RelayRestoreControllerIdentity);
    }
}

public bool CanExecuteDeviceRestoration
{
    get
    {
        return canExecuteDeviceRestoration;
    }
    private set
    {
        this.canExecuteDeviceRestoration = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("CanExecuteDeviceRestoration");
    }
}

public async void RelayRestoreControllerIdentity()
{
    await Task.Run(
    () =>
    {
        this.RestoreControllerIdentity();
    });
}

public bool InDatebase
{
    get
    {
        return DatabaseConnection.DeviceExists(this.IdentifiedSerialNumber);
    }
}
```

My question is how do I bind the behavior such that when the user click the `Button` the `TextBox` is validated, and if it fails it displays an error with a message and if it passes the `Button` will be disabled and the command will execute.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement IDataErrorInfo.
This would add an indexer which returns a string.
If empty string is returned it means no error.
You can return an empty string until button is pressed(u could use a flag).

when button is pressed,Run the validation logic and appropriately change the flag and Raise PropertyChanged event for IdentifiedSerialNumber 
You can learn how to implement IDataErrorInfo from [here](https://tarundotnet.wordpress.com/2011/03/03/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-idataerrorinfo-in-wpf/).
Also you need to Raise PropertyChanged event for IdentifiedSerialNumber.

Comment: Then how would I notify the text box that it should display an error?